# Add bootstrap in an android project

Tags: android, html, twitter-bootstrap, android-studio

i'm trying to build my first android app on intelliJ IDEA, so i' have decided to use html instead xml, so i followed this [guide](https://abhiandroid.com/androidstudio/add-local-html-file-android-studio.html).
Now i whant to use [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) on my html file, my first try was add that `link` tag inside the`head` tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

But nothing happened.
i' have find [this](https://github.com/Bearded-Hen/Android-Bootstrap) on github.

i' have done the steps in the **Quick start** section: [image]

added the dependencies in my build.gradle, nothing have changed.

idk if i'm doing someting wrong or what.

If someone know how can i add bootstrap to my android app, i' will really thanks

My project structure looks like this:

```
MyProject
    -APP
        -manifests
           AndroidManifest.xml
        -java
            -com.example.myapp
                MyApp.java
         -assets
             main.html
         -res
             -drawable
             -layout
             -mipmap
             -values

    -Gradle Scripts
        build.gradle(Project: )
        build.gradle(Module: )
```